# Prevent LocalReport Embedding Font into PDF

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, fonts, rdlc, localreport

When rendering a PDF using Calibri we have noticed file sizes to be hugely inflated in comparison to the same report using Arial.

Looking at the properties of the PDF it turns out this was due to `LocalReport.Render()` embedding a subset of Calibri within the PDF itself, leading to the increased file size:

[image]

Since we're happy that all recipients of the PDF will already have Calibri we need a way to prevent the font being embedded.

We're using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.Render with .rdlc

Answer (score 1):

It turns out we merely needed to add a key to the DeviceInfo.xml:

```
<DeviceInfo>
<EmbedFonts>None</EmbedFonts>
</DeviceInfo>
```

I found [the answer here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mariae/archive/2010/04/12/how-to-disable-this-font-embedding-in-reporting-services-2005-service-pack-3.aspx).